# Run different pl/sql scripts from one file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, toad

I have several PL/SQL scripts that are transforming data accoriding to specification day by day. I would like to run them in the loop for each day of the year. Is this possible to handle somehow in Toad?

I have found that I can run some other scripts by calling them via @name_of_script , but it doesn't work for me in Toad.

I just need something like:

```
BEGIN
FOR i IN day1 TO dayx
  EXECUTE SQL1;
  EXECUTE SQL2;
  EXECUTE SQL3;
END LOOP;
END
```

Is there any way how to run these scripts somehow "managed" except to change them to procedures? Thank you for answer.

Comment: Why Toad ? Can't you simply use sqlplus with `FOR /L %I (1,1,365) DO (sqlplus @script_1; sqlplus @script_2; sqlplus @script_3; )` ?

Comment: @Zilog80 that might be missing an `in`? But great idea, I'll be using that :)

Comment: @WilliamRobertson Yes, thanks. I've missed that one... I should make some pre-validation jscript just to check my syntax beforehand ^^. Rectified syntax including basic parallelization and the day as `&1`parameter for sql script : `FOR /L %I IN (1,1,365) DO (sqlplus @script_1 %I &; sqlplus @script_2 %I &; sqlplus @script_3 %I &; )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@` is an [SQLPlus command](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve002.htm#SQPUG024)

But toad partially supports it too: there are 2 common options:

1. Use SQL Editor - it should execute scripts in case of `@` command as in SQL*Plus
2. Use "Execute as script" --> "Execute via SQL plus": it should start SQL*plus connected to your database, there you can run your scripts.

Comment: Please, if I put there more @script.sql calls, they will run serial or parallel?

Comment: please, can you help? Because I am not sure (because of according order of error messeges) if  SQL Plus run all scripts "parallel" or "serial" if they are executed in one loop.